# PhpPgAdmin and select(max(num) from(select count(*) as num ... ) as counts)

Tags: sql, count, max, alias

I try this:

```
SELECT x.name 
FROM s x
WHERE (SELECT MAX(num) 
       FROM ((SELECT COUNT(*) AS num 
              FROM spj 
       WHERE n_post=x.n_post)>0) AS adf)
```

error message:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near ">
>
> LINE 2: ...CT count(*) as num from spj where n_post=x.n_post)>0) as adf...

Then i try this:

```
SELECT x.name 
FROM s x
WHERE (SELECT MAX(num) 
       FROM ((SELECT COUNT(*) AS num 
              FROM spj 
              WHERE n_post=x.n_post)) AS adf)
```

error message:

`ERROR:  argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type bigint
LINE 2: where (select max(num) from ((SELECT count(*) as num from sp..`

What is wrong? Please, help me.

Thx. My code:

```
SELECT x.name 
FROM s x
WHERE (SELECT MAX(num) 
       FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS num 
              FROM spj 
       WHERE x.n_post=n_post) AS adf)>0
```

I need n_post, which has the maximum number of entries in the table spj, but I do not know how to do it.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do with this query. If you need `adf` value you should define it in the SELECT list not in WHERE.

Comment: Your innermost subquery will always return exactly one value. What's the benefit of taking the max of that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need `n_post`, which has the maximum number of entries in the table `spj` try to use this query. This is MySQL query and it uses `LIMIT` keyword. If you use MsSQL then use `SELECT TOP 1` instead of `LIMIT 1`.

```
SELECT x.name 
FROM s x
JOIN (SELECT n_post,COUNT(*) AS num FROM spj GROUP BY n_post) as y
     on x.n_post=y.n_post
ORDER BY y.num DESC 
LIMIT 1
```